# JSF - XSLT rendering

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF (JSF2.0/Facelets) page which has a section (offers from an external vendor). The offers are presented in the form of an XML and are rendered as HTML using XSLT. How can I get the output of the XSLT rendered within the JSF page. 
I have other business functionality/forms on the page which I can render without any problem but I am looking for ideas on how to include a section rendered by an external XSLT processor.

Comment: how about using a <iframe> or an <h:outputText>?

Answer (score 0):

Check tomahawk [t:xmlTransform](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_xmlTransform.html). Transforms XML using and XSL stylesheet. The code is very simple to understand, so you can create our own variant too.